# Unity3d Рендеринг синусоидальной линии

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть задача , построить синусоидальный график из скрипта с дальнейшим рендерингом. Что бы при запуске сцены синусоида уже была построена , так как к ней будет добавляться персонаж движущийся по этой заданной траектории.
Какими способами можно отрисовать её ,с учётом того что в реальном времени будут меняться её амплитуда и частота?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html

Comment: @Andrey ответы в ответы

Comment: @RiotBr3aker это больше просто подсказка в какую сторону смотреть

Comment: А что подразумевается под "траектория синусоиды"? Персонаж будет двигаться по траектории синусоиды, скорость по оси X у него будет постоянной, будто он движется по прямой линии?